# Trying to get input and submit boxes on the same line

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I know this question has been asked lots, but I am a complete novice at coding and could therefore do with some help.

I'm adding a mailchimp subscribe box in a wordpress footer. I've followed instructions on how to customer the naked version to match formatting etc.

The final part is to get all three boxes in a single line at the bottom of the page. I just can't get my head around it.

Please help!

```css
#mailchimp {
  background: #F7C6CB;
  color: #3D6392;
  padding: 10px 7px;
}

#mailchimp input {
  border: medium none;
  color: #444;
  font-family: architects daughter;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

#mailchimp input.email {
  background: #fff
}

#mailchimp input.name {
  background: #fff
}

#mailchimp input[type="submit"] {
  background: #BBD8DC;
  color: #444;
  cursor: hand;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px 0;
}

#mailchimp input[type="submit"]:hover {
  color: #ffff
}
```

```html
<div id="mailchimp">

  <form action="//rocketfuelforlife.us16.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3234aff37dd880f87f2f30d0e&id=3f511425b1" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">

    <input type="text" size="30" value="Enter your first name" name="FNAME" class="name" id="mce-FNAME" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">

    <input type="email" size="30" value="Enter your email address" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">



    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
      <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
      <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear">
      <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
    </div>


  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around a bit with your code. I removed the `clear` class around your `input submit` and move the validation div below the `input`. I also reduced the `width` of the input to make sure they had enough space to align next to each other on one line. Run the code below the see the result of this:

```css
#mailchimp {
  background: #F7C6CB;
  color: #3D6392;
  padding: 10px 7px;
}

#mailchimp input {
  border: medium none;
  color: #444;
  font-family: architects daughter;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}

#mailchimp input.email {
  background: #fff
}

#mailchimp input.name {
  background: #fff
}

#mailchimp input[type="submit"] {
  background: #BBD8DC;
  color: #444;
  cursor: hand;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px 0;
}

#mailchimp input[type="submit"]:hover {
  color: #ffff
}
```

```html
<div id="mailchimp">

  <form action="//rocketfuelforlife.us16.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3234aff37dd880f87f2f30d0e&id=3f511425b1" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">

    <input type="text" size="30" value="Enter your first name" name="FNAME" class="name" id="mce-FNAME" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">

    <input type="email" size="30" value="Enter your email address" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">

      <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">

    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
      <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
      <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>


  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added "display: inline-block" style to both of the text inputs and also the submit input to force them onto the same line. I also moved the submit input out of the div.clear and put it directly under the email input, which allows it to be in the same line.

```css
#mailchimp {
  background: #F7C6CB;
  color: #3D6392;
  padding: 10px 7px;
}

#mailchimp input {
  border: medium none;
  color: #444;
  font-family: architects daughter;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#mailchimp input.email {
  background: #fff
}

#mailchimp input.name {
  background: #fff
}

#mailchimp input[type="submit"] {
  background: #BBD8DC;
  color: #444;
  cursor: hand;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

#mailchimp input[type="submit"]:hover {
  color: #ffff
}
```

```html
<div id="mailchimp">

  <form action="//rocketfuelforlife.us16.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=3234aff37dd880f87f2f30d0e&id=3f511425b1" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">

    <input type="text" size="30" value="Enter your first name" name="FNAME" class="name" id="mce-FNAME" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">

    <input type="email" size="30" value="Enter your email address" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">

<input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">

    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
      <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
      <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear">
      
    </div>


  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: hi Kyle, thanks for looking. The subscribe box has moved, but not the other two boxes. But thank you

Comment: @wixy I did not change the widths of the inputs, which makes it appear its not all on one line, but if you adjust the widths appropriately, it will be more responsive which is the ultimate goal.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just created parent divs for the `<input>` blocks and then I just floated the divs left and right and then changed the `#MailChimp` css style to have a height of 20px. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvyprt5L/2/)